# Reduce string length retrieved from database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, string

I am fetching rows with title & its description from MySQL database.
I want to alter the strings that I got from the database.

```
<div class="title"><?php $row['title']?></div>
<div class="details"><?php $row['desc']?></div>
```

So please tell me, how to apply javascript to this content (**$row['..']**)? Means, how I can access those strings in Javascript?

If the string length is more than 50 characters, I want to limit the string & add dots (...) to it.

Comment: `substr` is possible in php then why javasctipt

Comment: yup, I got it. Thanks by the way.

Comment: I bet if you search for "read more links" snippets, you get more advanced solutions that don't just cut off your strings at positions, you don't really want to ... (e.g. in the middle of a word, or destroying html if included)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using `substr`.

```
<?php echo (strlen($row['desc']) > 50) ? substr ($row['desc'] , 0, 50 ).'...' : $row['desc']; ?>
```

Comment: To append `...` only if greater than 50.

Comment: This one is short answer, thanks for it.. Both urs & Amal's answers are same just formats are changed.. So both of you thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It is better to use **`mb_substr()`** than **`substr()`**

```
<?php
echo mb_substr($row['title'],0,50);
```

**[Source](https://www.php.net/mb_substr)**

Answer (score 0):

Why do that? Html has a css for that. you can fix the width and add the "text-overflow:ellipsis".

Try this:

```
<div class="fixedWidth title"><?php $row['title']?></div>
<div class="fixedWidth details"><?php $row['desc']?></div>

<style>
    .fixedWidth{
        width:200px;
        white-space: nowrap;
        overflow: hidden;
        text-overflow:ellipsis;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with non-ASCII strings and you want to manipulate those then substr() is wrong to use. Instead you should use multibyte string functions, like [mb_substr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-substr.php) and [others](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php).

For that you must have mbstring-extension enabled for PHP. see http://php.net/manual/en/mbstring.installation.php

I would also not directly echo string for using javascript - you never know what chars could be there and then you should start to escape some chars to work properly with javascript.

Instead I would encourage you to use [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php). This will escape properly all special and UTF8-chars. 
PECL's json-extension must be enabled for json_* functions. See http://php.net/manual/en/json.installation.php

Of course if you are using [Zend](http://framework.zend.com/)-framework, then proper would be use [Zend_Json::encode()](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.json.basics.html)

```
<?php 
    $maxLength = 50;
    $encoding = 'UTF-8';
    $tail = ' ...';
    $row['desc'] = (mb_strlen($row['desc'], $encoding) > $maxLength) ? mb_substr($row['desc'], 0, $maxLength, $encoding) . $tail : $row['desc'];

?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var rowData = <?php echo json_encode($row); ?>;
    alert(rowData.desc);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

why don't you try in  directly php scripting insted of javascript.
you can make it as below.

```
<div class="title"><?php echo $title = strlen($row['title']) > 50 ? substr($row['title'], 0, 50)."..." : $row['title']; ?></div>
```

Then you can get the title in javascript as well.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 var title = $(".title").text();

});
```

Comment: If you put code use code button that will make 4 spaces at the begning of the line.